# Depreciation of Facebook graphapi search feature

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi guys have start exploring the facebook graph api for searching text in  the public posts but this exercise came to halt because came to know that this feature is supported in v1.0 and is its discontinued post April 2015. Can you guys point me to alternate solution and confirm the depreciation of search feature in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no equivalent feature for the deprecated public post search. So, there is no alternative.

Comment: OK is there alternative to it